# Retransforming classes on remote JVM using Java agent

Tags: javaagents

I try to retransform a class in a remote virtual machine (on the same host).
An agent (packed in jar with correct values in manifest) is loaded, but the transformer never called, although I ask the Instrumentation to retransform the class explicitly in my Agent agentmain method (I verified that the following code is called):

```
instrumentation.addTransformer(new MyClassFileTransformer(), true);
instrumentation.retransformClasses(Class.forName("example.MyClassToTransform"));
```

Any ideas why the retransformation doesn't happen and what should I fix?

Comment: Do u solve ur problem now?@JBaruch I have the same problem.

Comment: Actually, I did. I'll post the answer soon.

Comment: My problem was posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567552/how-to-retransform-a-class-at-runtime). Could you plz go in that page to give me some advices? thx a lot. @JBaruch