# How to retransform a class at runtime?

Tags: java, jvm, aop, cglib

I am trying to modify a class which is already loaded in a JVM. The solution which I found is this:

1. Attach an agent to a JVM specified by PID. (e.g. 8191)(Code: `AttachTest`)
2. Find the class which you want modified from those that have already been loaded in the JVM (e.g. 8191).
3. Add transformer using Instrument (Codes: `AgentMain`)
4. Modify the class (e.g. `Person`) in `transform` method (Code: `DemoTransformer`)
5. Retransform the class using [`retransformClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#RetransformClasses)

It works fine from 1st step to 5th step, but there are problems at `retransformClasses`. It called `transform` again which contains codes to modify class. And It modify other classes which I never wanna modify.
I think the problem may occured during `addTransformer` or `retransformClasses`. But I still confused. Well, how to retransform a class?

```
public class AttachTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AttachNotSupportedException,
        IOException, AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException { 
        String agentPath = "D:\\work\\workspace\\myjar\\loaded.jar";
        String vid = args[0]; 
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(vid);
        vm.loadAgent(agentPath);
    }
}
```

//Agent

```
public class AgentMain {
    public static void agentmain (String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, UnmodifiableClassException,
        InterruptedException {
    Class<?> [] allLoadedClasses = inst.getAllLoadedClasses();
        String tmpString = null;
        for (int i = 0; i<allLoadedClasses.length; i++) {
        tmpString = allLoadedClasses[i].getName();
        
        
        if (0 != tmpString.length()) {
            if (-1 != tmpString.lastIndexOf(".")) {
                tmpString = tmpString.substring(tmpString.lastIndexOf(".")+1,tmpString.length());
            }
            if (tmpString.equals("Person")) {

                inst.addTransformer(new DemoTransformer(), true);
                inst.retransformClasses(allLoadedClasses[i]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

|

```
public class DemoTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    @Override
    public byte[] transform (ClassLoader loader, String className,
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
        byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    
    ModifyMethodTest tm = new ModifyMethodTest(classfileBuffer);

    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        byteArray = tm.modiySleepMethod();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    return byteArray;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUTS:**
***THE ATTACH PROGRAM***

```
javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform [Person]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrow(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:856)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrowMaybeMBeanException(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:869)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:838)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1265)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1360)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:993)
    at AttachStackOverflow.main(AttachStackOverflow.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform [Person]
    at loaded3.TransformerService.transform(TransformerService.java:75)
    at loaded3.TransformerService.transformClass(TransformerService.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:93)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:27)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:208)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:120)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:262)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1265)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1360)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:124)
    at loaded3.TransformerService.transform(TransformerService.java:72)
    ... 31 more
```

**OUTPUTS:** *TARGET PROGRAM*

```
print Call sayHello()
print Hello World!
Supported Redefine
Supported Retransform
Call transform() in TransformerService
Add transformer
support redefine. return TRUE
support retransforme. return TRUE
IsModifiable class "class Person". return TRUE
Retransform classes
Number of times to Call transform() in DemoTransformer:1
####ASM CODE####
consturct ModifyMethodTest
Call modifySleepMethod
new classreader
new classwriter
construct ModifyClassAdapter
sayHello
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #5
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #13
[arg1] = java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit  [arg2] = sleep  #22
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #30
sayHello2
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #5
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #13
<init>
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = java/lang/Object  [arg2] = <init>  #1
main
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = Person  [arg2] = <init>  #4
[arg1] = Person  [arg2] = sayHello  #9
[arg1] = Person  [arg2] = sayHello2  #13
[arg1] = java/lang/InterruptedException  [arg2] = printStackTrace  #21
getName
consturct Modifymethod
setName
consturct Modifymethod
Call visitend
Finished to call modifymethodtest
####End of ASM CODE
Remove transformer
Call transform() in TransformerService
Add transformer
support redefine. return TRUE
support retransforme. return TRUE
IsModifiable class "class Person". return TRUE
Retransform classes
Number of times to Call transform() in DemoTransformer:2
####ASM CODE####
consturct ModifyMethodTest
Call modifySleepMethod
new classreader
new classwriter
construct ModifyClassAdapter
sayHello
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #5
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #13
[arg1] = java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit  [arg2] = sleep  #22
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #30
sayHello2
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #5
[arg1] = java/io/PrintStream  [arg2] = println  #13
<init>
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = java/lang/Object  [arg2] = <init>  #1
main
consturct Modifymethod
[arg1] = Person  [arg2] = <init>  #4
[arg1] = Person  [arg2] = sayHello  #9
[arg1] = Person  [arg2] = sayHello2  #13
[arg1] = java/lang/InterruptedException  [arg2] = printStackTrace  #21
getName
consturct Modifymethod
setName
consturct Modifymethod
Call visitend
Finished to call modifymethodtest
####End of ASM CODE
Remove transformer
print in sayHello()
print Call sayHello2()
print Hello World!2
```

Comment: Method `transform()` in class DemoTransformer was called when call `addTransformer(new DemoTransformer)`. But It should no be called again. Actually, It did happen. Maybe it was called after calling `retransformClasses`. I am not sure. @JBaruch

Comment: I need add a line to the class. For example, to call `sleep` method, to add `System.out.println` statement, etc.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Short Answer**

- Don't iterate through all the loaded classes from Instrumentation. Instead, just examine the class name passed in to the transformer and if it matches your target class, then transform it. Otherwise, simply return the passed classfileBuffer unmodified.
- Make the set up calls outside the transformer, (i.e. in your case, do the following from your agent) so initialize your transformer with the class name you're looking to transform (this will be the *inner format* so instead of **foo.bar.Snafu**, you will be looking to match against **foo/bar/Snafu**. Then add the transformer, call retransform and then remove the transformer.
- In order to call retransform, you will need the actual [pre-transform] class which you can find by calling *Class.forName* (in the agentmain), or if you absolutely have to, you could find it in *Intrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses()* as a last resort. If the target class has not been loaded, you will need the classloader to call *Class.forName(name, boolean, classloader)* in which case you can pass the URL to the target class class-path in the agent main string args.

**Long Answer**

Here's a few recommendations:

1. Separate out the operation you're calling into 2 separate operations:

   1. Install the agent. This only needs to be done once.
   2. Transform the target class[es]. You might want to do this *n* times.
2. I would implement 1.2 by registering a simple JMX MBean when you install the agent. This MBean should provide an operation like `public void transformClass(String className)`. and should be initialized with a reference to the agent's acquired **Instrumentation** instance. The MBean class, interface and any required 3rd party classes should be included in your agent's **loaded.jar**. It should also contain your **ModifyMethodTest** class (which I assume it already does).
3. At the same time that you install your agent jar, also install the management agent from **$JAVA_HOME/lib/management-agent.jar** which will activate the management agent so you can invoke the transform operation in the MBean you're about to register.
4. Parameterize your DemoTransformer class to accept the *internal form* of the name of the class you want to transform. (i.e. if your binary class name is *foo.bar.Snafu*, the internal form will be *foo/bar/Snafu*. As your DemoTransformer instance starts getting transform callbacks, ignore all class names that do not match the internal form class name you specified. (i.e. simply return the classfileBuffer unmodified)
5. Your tranformer MBean **transformClass** operation should then:

   1. Convert the passed class name to internal form.
   2. Create a new DemoTransformer, passing the internal form class name.
   3. Register the DemoTransformer instance using `Instrumentation.addTransformer(theNewDemoTransformer, true)` .
   4. Call `Instrumentation.retransformClasses(ClassForName(className))`  (with the binary class name passed to the MBean operation). When this call returns, your class will be transformed.
   5. Remove the transformer with `Intrumentation.removeTransformer(theNewDemoTransformer)`.

The following is an untested approximation of what I mean:

**Transformer MBean**

```
public interface TransformerServiceMBean {
    /**
     * Transforms the target class name
     * @param className The binary name of the target class
     */
    public void transformClass(String className);
}
```

**Transformer Service**

```
public class TransformerService implements TransformerServiceMBean {
    /** The JVM's instrumentation instance */
    protected final Instrumentation instrumentation;

    /**
     * Creates a new TransformerService
     * @param instrumentation  The JVM's instrumentation instance 
     */
    public TransformerService(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        this.instrumentation = instrumentation;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @see com.heliosapm.shorthandexamples.TransformerServiceMBean#transformClass(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void transformClass(String className) {
        Class<?> targetClazz = null;
        ClassLoader targetClassLoader = null;
        // first see if we can locate the class through normal means
        try {
            targetClazz = Class.forName(className);
            targetClassLoader = targetClazz.getClassLoader();
            transform(targetClazz, targetClassLoader);
            return;
        } catch (Exception ex) { /* Nope */ }
        // now try the hard/slow way
        for(Class<?> clazz: instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses()) {
            if(clazz.getName().equals(className)) {
                targetClazz = clazz;
                targetClassLoader = targetClazz.getClassLoader();
                transform(targetClazz, targetClassLoader);
                return;             
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to locate class [" + className + "]");
    }

    /**
     * Registers a transformer and executes the transform
     * @param clazz The class to transform
     * @param classLoader The classloader the class was loaded from
     */
    protected void transform(Class<?> clazz, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        DemoTransformer dt = new DemoTransformer(clazz.getName(), classLoader);
        instrumentation.addTransformer(dt, true);
        try {
            instrumentation.retransformClasses(clazz);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to transform [" + clazz.getName() + "]", ex);
        } finally {
            instrumentation.removeTransformer(dt);
        }       
    }
}
```

**The Class Transformer**

```
public class DemoTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
    /** The internal form class name of the class to transform */
    protected String className;
    /** The class loader of the class */
    protected ClassLoader classLoader;
    /**
     * Creates a new DemoTransformer
     * @param className The binary class name of the class to transform
     * @param classLoader The class loader of the class
     */
    public DemoTransformer(String className, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        this.className = className.replace('.', '/');
        this.classLoader = classLoader;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @see java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer#transform(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.security.ProtectionDomain, byte[])
     */
    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
            Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
            byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        if(className.equals(this.className) && loader.equals(classLoader)) {
            return new ModifyMethodTest(classfileBuffer).modiySleepMethod();
        }
        return classfileBuffer;
    }

}
```

**The Agent**

```
public class AgentMain {

    public static void agentmain (String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws Exception {
        TransformerService ts = new TransformerService(inst);
        ObjectName on = new ObjectName("transformer:service=DemoTransformer");
        // Could be a different MBeanServer. If so, pass a JMX Default Domain Name in agentArgs
        MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        server.registerMBean(ts, on);
        // Set this property so the installer knows we're already here
        System.setProperty("demo.agent.installed", "true");     
    }

}
```

**The Agent Installer**

```
public class AgentInstaller {
    /**
     * Installs the loader agent on the target JVM identified in <code>args[0]</code>
     * and then transforms all the classes identified in <code>args[1..n]</code>.
     * @param args The target JVM pid in [0] followed by the classnames to transform
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String agentPath = "D:\\work\\workspace\\myjar\\loaded.jar";
        String vid = args[0]; 
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(vid);
        // Check to see if transformer agent is installed
        if(!vm.getSystemProperties().contains("demo.agent.installed")) {
            vm.loadAgent(agentPath);  
            // that property will be set now, 
            // and the transformer MBean will be installed
        }
        // Check to see if connector is installed
        String connectorAddress = vm.getAgentProperties().getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress", null);
        if(connectorAddress==null) {
            // It's not, so install the management agent
            String javaHome = vm.getSystemProperties().getProperty("java.home");
            File managementAgentJarFile = new File(javaHome + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "management-agent.jar");
            vm.loadAgent(managementAgentJarFile.getAbsolutePath());
            connectorAddress = vm.getAgentProperties().getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress", null);
            // Now it's installed
        }
        // Now connect and transform the classnames provided in the remaining args.
        JMXConnector connector = null;
        try {
            // This is the ObjectName of the MBean registered when loaded.jar was installed.
            ObjectName on = new ObjectName("transformer:service=DemoTransformer");
            // Here we're connecting to the target JVM through the management agent
            connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(connectorAddress));
            MBeanServerConnection server = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
            for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                String className = args[i];
                // Call transformClass on the transformer MBean
                server.invoke(on, "transformClass", new Object[]{className}, new String[]{String.class.getName()});
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } finally {
            if(connector!=null) try { connector.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        // Done. (Hopefully)
    }
}
```

**================= UPDATE =================**

Hey Nick;  Yep, that's one of the limitations of the current (i.e. Java 5-8) class transformers. 
To quote from the [Instrumentation javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html):

> "The retransformation may change method bodies, the constant pool and
>   attributes. The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields
>   or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance.
>   These restrictions maybe be lifted in future versions. The class file
>   bytes are not checked, verified and installed until after the
>   transformations have been applied, if the resultant bytes are in error
>   this method will throw an exception."

As an aside, this same limitation is documented verbatim for redefining classes too.

As such, you have 2 options:

1. Don't add new methods. This is commonly very limiting and disqualifies the use of very common byte-code AOP patterns like method
   wrapping. Depending on which byte-code manipulation library you're using, you may be able to inject all the functionality you want into
   the existing methods. Some libraries make this easier than others. Or, I should say, some libraries will make this easier than others.
2. Transform the class before it is class loaded. This uses the same general pattern of the code we already discussed, except you don't trigger
   the transform through calling retransformClasses. Rather, you register the ClassFileTransformer to perform the transform *before* the class is loaded
   and your target class will be modified when it is first class loaded. In this case, you're pretty much free to modify the class any way you 
   like, provided the end product can still be validated. Beating the application to the punch (i.e. getting your ClassFileTransformer 
   registered before the application loads the class) will most likely require a command like **javaagent**, although if you have tight control
   of the lifecycle of your application, it is possible to do this in more traditional application layer code. As I said, you just need to make
   sure you get the transformer registered before the target class is loaded.

One other variation on #2 you may be able to use is to *simulate* a brand new class by using a new classloader. If you create a new 
isolated classloader which will not delegate to the existing [loaded] class, but does have access to the [unloaded] target class byte-code,
you're essentially reproducing the requirements of #2 above since the JVM considers this to be a brand new class.

**================  UPDATE  ================**

In your last comments, I feel like I've lost track a bit of where you are. At any rate, Oracle JDK 1.6 most definitely supports retransform. I am not too familiar with ASM, but the last error you posted indicates that the ASM transformation somehow modified the class schema which is not allowed, so the retransform failed.

I figured a working example would add more clarity. The same classes as above (plus one test class called Person) are [here](https://gist.github.com/nickman/6494990). There's a couple of modifications/additions:

- The transform operation in the [TransformerService](https://gist.github.com/nickman/6494990#file-transformerservice-java) now has 3 parameters:

  1. The binary class name
  2. The method name to instrument
  3. A [regular] expression to match the method signature. (if null or empty, matches all signatures)
  4. The actual bytecode modification is done using [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) in the [ModifyMethodTest](https://gist.github.com/nickman/6494990#file-modifymethodtest-java) class. All the instrumentation does is add a *System.out.println* that looks like this:  `-->Invoked method [com.heliosapm.shorthandexamples.Person.sayHello((I)V)]`
- The [AgentInstaller](https://gist.github.com/nickman/6494990#file-agentinstaller-java) (which has the demo's Main) just self-installs the agent and the transform service. (Easier for Dev/Demo purposes, but will still work with other JVMs)
- Once the agent is self-installed, the main thread creates a [Person](https://gist.github.com/nickman/6494990#file-person-java) instance and just loops, calling the Person's two *sayHello* methods.

Prior to transform, that output looks as follows.

```
Temp File:c:\temp\com.heliosapm.shorthandexamples.AgentMain8724970986698386534.jar
Installing AgentMain...
AgentMain Installed
Agent Loaded
Instrumentation Deployed:true
Hello [0]
Hello [0]
Hello [1]
Hello [-1]
Hello [2]
Hello [-2]
```

Person has 2 *sayHello* methods, one takes an **int**, the other takes a **String**. (The String one just prints the negative of the loop index).

Once I start the AgentInstaller, the agent is installed and Person is being invoked in a loop, I connect to the JVM using JConsole:

[image: Finding the AgentInstaller JVM]

I navigate to the TransformerService MBean and invoke the **transformClass** operation. I supply the fully qualified class [binary] name, the method name to instrument, and a regex expression **(I)V** which matches *only* the *sayHello* method which takes an int as an argument. (Or I could supply **.***, or nothing to match all overloads). I execute the operation.

[image: Invoking the operation]

Now when I go back to the running JVM and examine the output:

```
Examining class [com/heliosapm/shorthandexamples/Person]
Instrumenting class [com/heliosapm/shorthandexamples/Person]
[ModifyMethodTest] Adding [System.out.println("\n\t-->Invoked method [com.heliosapm.shorthandexamples.Person.sayHello((I)V)]");]
[ModifyMethodTest] Intrumented [1] methods

    -->Invoked method [com.heliosapm.shorthandexamples.Person.sayHello((I)V)]
Hello [108]
Hello [-108]

    -->Invoked method [com.heliosapm.shorthandexamples.Person.sayHello((I)V)]
Hello [109]
Hello [-109]
```

Done. Method instrumented.

Keep in mind, the reason the retransform is allowed is because the Javassist bytecode modification made no changes other than to inject code into an existing method.

Make sense ?

Comment: I tried the code above. I got the error. `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)` @Nicholas

Comment: `Can-Redefine-Classes: true` `Can-Retransform-Classes: true` `isModifiableClass` return true. JDK 1.6

Comment: `retransformClasses()` was called twice in debug mode. Never called when normal running. I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605025/failed-to-redefine-class-when-i-try-to-retransform-class), for more detail. It really make me crazy. Can anyone give me some advice? @Nicholas

Comment: At first, thx for ur time and generous help. I didnt add a method, I was trying modify a method. Now, the problem is `transform()` was called twice. `retransformClasses()` seems be called twice too, and it give me an error at the second time to call `retransformClasses()` after the second time to call `transform()`. I am confused about [when to call `transform()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain,%20byte[]%29) . @Nicholas

Comment: [Once a transformer has been registered with addTransformer, the transformer will be called for every new class definition and every class redefinition. Retransformation capable transformers will also be called on every class retransformation. The request for a new class definition is made with ClassLoader.defineClass or its native equivalents. ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain,%20byte[]%29)

Comment: I posted My code at codepad. @Nicholas Eight file in agent package-`loaded3.jar`. Insturment&transform codes: [1](http://codepad.org/K1brIpNf) [2](http://codepad.org/t5usDWCa) [3](http://codepad.org/1iS07LZK) [4](http://codepad.org/7Ccyrlyv) [5](http://testattach.codepad.org/E6C1Al2K). ASM codes:[1](http://codepad.org/wahGPENS) [2](http://codepad.org/klbbQ3uE) [3](http://codepad.org/9mfLTEwx). [One target class](http://testattach.codepad.org/G6pb2oVf). [One attach file](http://testattach.codepad.org/OyTQM7LY). Can you help me to have a look. Most of them is follow your answer above. thx

Comment: referenced libraries: `tools.jar` [`org.objectweb.asm_3.3.1.v201105211655.jar`](http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sginterpreter/Repository/plugins/org.objectweb.asm_3.3.1.v201105211655.jar)

Comment: `transform()` in `DemoTransformer` is called twice.

Comment: Can you post the output when you run the code you referenced ?

Comment: I found that [[`classReader.accept(classAdapter, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG);`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657095/got-unsupportedoperationexception-when-try-to-retransformclasses)] make the program catch [`UnsupportedOperationException`] at [`throw new RuntimeException("Failed to transform [" + clazz.getName() + "]", ex);`], even though I did not modify any field or method in my ASM code. And the exception call `transform()` again, so that `transfrom()` was called twice.

Comment: I can post outputs on monday. Outputs in the thread of target class works fine. The thread of attach program give error.

Comment: I have posted my outputs above. source codes in loaded3.jar:{[AgentMain](http://codepad.org/4l4DX46G) [DemoTransformer](http://codepad.org/QDWed6bH) {ASMCODE:[ModifyMethod](http://codepad.org/6eTLqzgy) [ModifyMethodClassAdapter](http://codepad.org/OP5xE3wZ) [ModifyMethodTest](http://codepad.org/zNi7Axm1)} {MBean:[TransformerService](http://codepad.org/5OfSOjuY) [TransformerServiceBean](http://codepad.org/1iS07LZK)} [MANIFEST.MF](http://codepad.org/K1brIpNf)} [Attach Program](http://testattach.codepad.org/OyTQM7LY) [Target Program](http://codepad.org/p7QrfL3l) @Nicholas thx for ur time.

Comment: Well, The exception is caused by a stupid mistake which I did add a field to target class in my ASM code. And It is not supported to retransform in oracle JDK 1.6 for now.

Comment: Yes, it is caused by ASM code which add a field to target class.

Comment: Using foo.bar.Snafu instead of foo/bar/Snafu as an argument of invoke() in this program.

Comment: First time logging in just to upvote an answer