# Why does cglib not proxy super invocations?

Tags: java, interceptor, cglib

I have following structure below (I used annotation `@Intercepted` to indicate the method which is intercepted): When I call intercepted method as `intercepted()` without using 
super keyword an interceptor is called as expected. However when called in the following way `super.intercepted()` interception is never called. Why is this the case?

```
public class Base {
   @Intercepted
   public void intercepted() {}
}

public class BaseImpl extends Base {    
   public void doSomething() {
     super.intercepted(); //<-- does not work
     intercepted(); //<--- without the super, it works
   }
}
```

Comment: What version of cglib do you use? Have you tried downgrading/upgrading it?

Comment: Im using it as dependency to objectify. I'm not sure if this have anything to do with the version.

Comment: You might want to change your question title to something: *Why does cglib not proxy super invocations?* or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the generated byte code, both in the byte code generated by the Java compiler for `super.method` compared to `this.method` and in the byte code generated by cglib for the proxy. In order to intercept a method, cglib adds a new class to the type hierarchy. All instances of your proxied class will then be of a different run time type which is a subclass of your proxied class. For your example, this results in a type hierarchy similar to the following:

```
class Base { 
  void intercepted() { ... }
}

class BaseImpl extends Base { 
  void doSomething() { ... }
}

class BaseImpl$$cglib extends BaseImpl { 
  @Override void intercepted() { ... }
}
```

Now the Java compiler comes into place. The Java compiler invokes methods by one of for byte code instructions. Each of those instructions result in a different runtime behavior. The two instructions that are important here are the most common:

- `INVOKEVIRTUAL`: The invocation `this.intercepted` is translated into a dynamic/virtual method invocation by the Java compiler. As a consequence of a dynamic call, the Java run time will look at the **current type's virtual method table** in order to decide which method is to be invoked. The method is [bound dynamically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). This means, if you are invoking `intercepted` from an instance of `BaseImpl$$cglib`, the selected method will be `BaseImpl$$cglib.intercepted`. If you are invoking the method from a type `BaseImpl$$cglib`, the method invoked will instead be `Base.intercepted` because `BaseImpl` does not override `intercepted`. Obviously, `Base.intercepted` will invoke the method defined in its own class.
- `INVOKESTATIC`: Static invocations are **not bound dynamically** at run time. In order to call `super.intercepted`, the Java run time should invoke the method of the **super type's virtual method table**. This means, that `BaseImpl` will explicitly reference the method table of `Base`. As a result, the virtual method table of `BaseImpl$$cglib` is never consulted and the calls cannot be intercepted. This is basically the same reason for which it is not possible to intercept static methods. Within byte code, static methods and super invocations are treated exactly the same.

This said, for `super.intercepted`, the cglib proxy is never hit. It is not possible to instrument loaded classes in Java (well, you can [push this rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567552/how-to-retransform-a-class-at-runtime/18576798#18576798) a little), such that no proxy framework can actually do what you intend.

Comment: Any other interception technology can workaround this?

Comment: You could instrument the super class directly. This is possible by using a more powerful instrumentation library such as javassist or ASM where you can rewrite class definitions and not only create subclasses. Classes can be redefined before application start up by overriding their definitions or at run by using a java agent (via the Attach API).