# Remote Runtime Instrumentation

Tags: java, instrumentation, agent, javassist, javaagents

I am new at instrumentation world.
I am trying to instrumentate a remote JVM at Runtime.
Actually, i have to log all classes or part of them and transform them..
I have read many documents and i found this code [HERE](https://gist.github.com/nickman/6494990)

I changed the code and i replaced

```
// Run sayHello in a loop
Person person = new Person();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    person.sayHello(i);
    person.sayHello("" + (i*-1));
    Thread.currentThread().join(5000);
}
```

by this one:

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    String className = args[i] ;
    System.out.println("className" + className);
    // Call transformClass on the transformer MBean
    server.invoke(on, "transformClass", new Object[]{className}, new String[]{String.class.getName()});
}
```

But i found that args.length=0
I don't know what the args[] contain...And if it contains loaded classes (i assume) then why it is empty..

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote that code, but I don't understand what you're trying to do in your code. The referenced github gists were in reference to the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567552/how-to-retransform-a-class-at-runtime), so it may help you to re-read that question.

There are multiple steps involved, and the classes need to be packaged in a specific way, but the basics are:

1. Use the AgentInstaller to install the instrumentation agent into a running JVM.
2. Connect to the JVM via JMX.
3. Invoke the `transformClass(String className, String methodName, String methodSignature)` MBean operation to instrument the class using the demo transformer.

Comment: thnx @Nicholas... it's done ;)

But i want to ask you an other question: with your code on github, could I instrument classes witch are locatedin another application?

Comment: @GEmyy; Yup. That's the idea. Install the agent into the target app, then instrument it.

Comment: thnx @Nicholas, but how should i install the agent into the target app? the "AgentInstaller" Class exists in my program But i want to instrumentate another application.. Should I just change the PID in the AgentInstaller Class or what exactely?

Comment: Because when i do this:

 VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid_of_the _other_app);

I got 2 crashed apps